# SQL: Upsert and get the old and the new values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, upsert, sql-merge

I have the following table Items:

```
Id          MemberId          MemberGuid        ExpiryYear         Hash    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
1           1                 Guid1             2017               Hash1
2           1                 Guid2             2018               Hash2
3           2                 Guid3             2020               Hash3
4           2                 Guid4             2017               Hash1
```

I need to copy the items from a member to another (not just to update MemberId, to insert a new record). The rule is: if I want to migrate all the items from a member to another, I will have to check that that item does not exists in the new member.

For example, if I want to move the items from member 1 to member 2, I will move only item with id 2, because I already have an item at member 2 with the same hash and with the same expiry year (this are the columns that I need to check before inserting the new items).

How to write a query that migrates only the non-existing items from a member to another and get the old id and the new id of the records? Somehow with an upsert?

Comment: I am using Sql server 2014

Comment: MemberGuid is copied from old item or is calculated? where old id will be recorded?

Comment: is generated as new guid, only expiry year and hash is copied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can as the below:

```
-- MOCK DATA
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE
(    
    Id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    MemberId INT,
    MemberGuid CHAR(5),
    ExpiryYear CHAR(4),
    Hash CHAR(5)
)   

INSERT INTO @Tbl        
VALUES
(1, 'Guid1', '2017', 'Hash1'),
(1, 'Guid2', '2018', 'Hash1'),
(2, 'Guid3', '2020', 'Hash3'),
(2, 'Guid4', '2017', 'Hash1')
-- MOCK DATA

-- Parameters
DECLARE @FromParam INT = 1 
DECLARE @ToParam INT = 2


DECLARE @TmpTable TABLE (NewDataId INT, OldDataId INT)

MERGE @Tbl AS T
USING
(
    SELECT * FROM @Tbl
    WHERE MemberId = @FromParam
) AS F
ON  T.Hash = F.Hash AND 
    T.ExpiryYear = F.ExpiryYear AND 
    T.MemberId = @ToParam
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT ( MemberId, MemberGuid, ExpiryYear, Hash) 
    VALUES ( @ToParam, F.MemberGuid, F.ExpiryYear, F.Hash)
    OUTPUT inserted.Id, F.Id INTO @TmpTable;

SELECT * FROM @TmpTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

```
Get in cursor all the data of member 1
```

Step 2:

```
 While moving through cursor.
        Begin
        select hash, expirydate from items where memberid=2 and hash=member1.hash and expirydate=member1.expirydate
```

Step 3

```
If above brings any result, do not insert.

       else insert.
```

Hope this helps

Note: this is not actual code. I am providing you just steps based on which you can write sql.

Comment: you can use @@ROWCOUNT(return no of items Member1 has) in a while loop and then insert for memebr2 after checking in if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you just need an insert. When `ExpiryYear` and `Hash` matched you don't wanna do anything. You just wanna insert from source to target where those columns doesn't match. You can do that with `Merge` or `Insert`.

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable
(
    Oldid INT,
    OldMemberId INT,
    Id INT,
    MemberId INT,
    MemberGuid CHAR(5),
    ExpiryYear CHAR(4),
    Hash CHAR(5)
)   

INSERT INTO YourTable VALUES

(null, null, 1, 1, 'Guid1', '2017', 'Hash1'),
(null, null, 2, 1, 'Guid2', '2018', 'Hash2'),
(null, null, 3, 2, 'Guid3', '2020', 'Hash3'),
(null, null, 4, 2, 'Guid4', '2017', 'Hash1')

DECLARE @SourceMemberID AS INT = 1
DECLARE @TargetMemberID AS INT = 2

MERGE [YourTable] AS t
USING
(
    SELECT * FROM [YourTable]
    WHERE MemberId = @SourceMemberID
) AS s
ON t.Hash = s.Hash AND t.ExpiryYear = s.ExpiryYear AND t.MemberId = @TargetMemberID
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT(Oldid, OldMemberId, Id, MemberId, MemberGuid, ExpiryYear, Hash) VALUES (s.Id, s.MemberId, (SELECT MAX(Id) + 1 FROM [YourTable]), @TargetMemberID, s.MemberGuid, s.ExpiryYear, s.Hash);

SELECT * FROM YourTable

DROP TABLE YourTable

/* Output:
Oldid   OldMemberId Id  MemberId    MemberGuid  ExpiryYear  Hash
-----------------------------------------------------------------
NULL    NULL        1   1           Guid1       2017        Hash1
NULL    NULL        2   1           Guid2       2018        Hash2
NULL    NULL        3   2           Guid3       2020        Hash3
NULL    NULL        4   2           Guid4       2017        Hash1
2       1           5   2           Guid2       2018        Hash2
```

If you just want to select then do as following

```
SELECT null AS OldID, null AS OldMemberID, Id, MemberId, MemberGuid, ExpiryYear, Hash FROM YourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT A.Id AS OldID, A.MemberId AS OldMemberID, (SELECT MAX(Id) + 1 FROM YourTable) AS Id, @TargetMemberID AS MemberId, A.MemberGuid, A.ExpiryYear, A.Hash
FROM YourTable A
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE MemberId = @TargetMemberID
) B ON A.ExpiryYear = B.ExpiryYear AND A.Hash = B.Hash
WHERE A.MemberId = @SourceMemberID AND B.Id IS NULL
```

Comment: but I will need to get also the old id of migrated items

Comment: when I'm migrating from member 1 to member 2, this should be the output of the migrated items:
OldId, OldMemberId, newId, NewmemberId
2,1,5,2

Comment: In which column you want migrated rows' old id ?

Comment: You want to add two new columns `oldId` and `oldMemberid` ? For that you must have two extra nullable columns in your table. Otherwise how you gonna insert 7 columns(oldId, oldMemberId, Id, MemberId, MemberGuid, ExpiryYear, Hash) in a 5 column table?

Comment: So 1: migrate the items, 2: return back the old id and the new id. I would prefer to do this without altering the table structure

Comment: the old id should be selected as the result of the query, I don't want to save it anywhere, it will be just an output that will be written in a file

Comment: Well actually then you don't need any insert or merge. You just need a select. I am updating my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127260/discussion-between-tanjim-rahman-and-buda-gavril).